# Is there a tree that can rank an object?

Tags: java, collections

I"ve coded a Red Black binary statistic tree to get the rank of an arbitrary object that is comparable to the other objects in the Red Black tree. I wonder if there is an API class that provides the same functionality.

It would also be nice if given a rank, the class has a function to return an object of that rank within the tree.

Note that the Red-black BST allows these two operations in log(n) time where n is the number of objects in the tree.

Comment: You mean you implemented an order statistic tree? I don't think those are in the Java stdlib.

Comment: java.util.TreeSet uses a red-black tree implemented by a java.util.TreeMap. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework

Comment: How do people normally rank objects in a dynamically formed data structure such as a tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard API doesn't have an order statistic tree. `TreeMap` in particular doesn't have methods for finding the rank of a key, or finding a key by rank in O(log n) time.

It doesn't look like usual add-on libraries (Apache Commons Collections, Google Guava) have an order statistic tree, either.

Comment: google's guava team seems to be working on it based on email.

Answer (score 4):

Check out http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/33balanced/RedBlackBST.java.html.

Prof. Sedgewick named the trees as RedBlack, so, most probably, it's a correct implementation of RedBlack BSTs. It has rank too (running in O(lgN)). (I would not risk writing my own version if it supports deletion). That's at least a good reference. (Not in java.util alas)

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
>
> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.

---

*It would also be nice if given a rank, the class has a function to return an object of that rank within the tree.*

The `NavigableMap` interface (implemented by TreeMap) offers methods such as `floorKey` and `ceilingKey`.

Comment: Which of the problems I posed does this solve in log(n) time?

Comment: @fodon I had misunderstood your need. You could put the objects as keys and a dummy value. You can then call `map.headMap().size()` to get the rank (not sure if it is O(log(n))). But I'm not sure how you will get access to the n-th item with that methodology.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea. It would be interesting to know if it is log(n) process to find size()  of the headmap()

Comment: Just checked and it looks like size() is a O(n) process. It iterates through all elements in the subtree. Look at the AscendingSubMap class in TreeMap and see how it gets to size().